# MySQL - order rows with a column from another table and don't repeat data

Tags: mysql, join, distinct, repeat

- update -
  nevermind i fix it with php side and use "distinct" the final query (solution) is this :

  SELECT  Distinct m.idDenuncia  FROM denunciaMedicamentos AS m JOIN denuncias AS p WHERE p.id=m.idDenuncia  ORDER BY m.medicamento

---

```
SELECT * FROM denunciaMedicamentos AS m
JOIN denuncias AS p
WHERE p.id=m.idDenuncia
ORDER BY m.medicamento
```

And it works, but it repeats columns `id` and `idDenuncia`. This is the result :

[image: result]

`idDenuncia` is the reference to denuncias table.

I want to know, what can I do so it doesn't repeat data (`id`)?

Comment: select columns you want in the result instead of *

Comment: yep, thanks @Oldskool
But.. i want to know what can i do to prevent repeat values for "idDenuncia" column?

Comment: Use m.idDenuncia in select.

Answer (score 1):

Select all from one table and selected from another will solve your problem

```
SELECT  m.*,p.col1,p.col2 FROM denunciaMedicamentos AS m JOIN denuncias AS p WHERE p.id=m.idDenuncia  ORDER BY m.medicamento
```

Comment: thanks for help me,
i want to know what can i do to prevent repeat values for "idDenuncia" column?

Answer (score 0):

Now, i get it you do not want 128 to repeat in your results. If that is what you want use:

```
SELECT distinct(m.idDenuncia) FROM denunciaMedicamentos AS m JOIN denuncias AS p WHERE p.id=m.idDenuncia ORDER BY m.medicamento
```

Comment: But you still need to check your entries...the reason you have two records is because you have two corresponding entries for the id